# Опасная команда rm /

Tags: linux, shell

Каждый раз когда пишу

```
rm /...
```

Боюсь после слэша на ентер нажать. Если что, потребуется ли подтверждение или стоит дальше опасаться?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Если боитесь нажать `Enter`, в таком случае лучше добавлять флаг `-i`

```
rm -i ./file.txt
```

В данном случае перед удалением высветится сообщение о подтверждении данного действия.

А для того, чтобы постоянно не вводить данный флаг, просто добавьте `alias` в `.bashrc`

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

Comment: Спасибо, открыл для себя мир алиасов :)

Answer (score 14):

Без флага `--no-preserve-root` `rm -rf /` на современных дистрибутивах не запустится:

> --no-preserve-root
>     do not treat '/' specially

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html

Answer (score 11):

`rm` без флага `-r` не удалит каталог в принципе. Так же нечего бояться если Вы не сидите под `root` Как уже ответили флаг `-i` является защитой от случайного удаления, лично я имею привычку сначала заходить в каталог, в котором хочу что-то удалить, если писать полный путь, всегда есть вероятность ошибиться и это не обязательно `Enter` после слеша...